# CCLabelBMFont has empty space on the top and bottom...how to remove?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

When I generate a CCLabelBMFont object, the font seems to include some leading whitespace on the top and bottom of the characters, and this empty space is included in the font object that I create. Sometimes, I need to position the object precisely by the top and bottom, and this offset ruins my spacing. I want to do is trim the font so that its bounds and content size is only the space in which there are no pixels with an alpha greater than 0.

Comment: which tool u used for font file creation ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Glyph Designer you can export FNT/PNG files. Although the parameter is not exposed in GlyphDesigner GUI, you can modify (decrease) the lineHeight parameter directly in the FNT file. You can also change the yOffset parameter for every character included in your font.

It makes it a little harder to maintain as those manual changes will be overwritten each time you re-publish with GlyphDesigner, but at least you have a way to adress your problem.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like Glyph Designer to set the padding and spacing parameters for your BMFont. 
Glyph Designer: http://glyphdesigner.71squared.com

Comment: There is only one property for that (spacing), which adds space to both axes. The empty space I'm referring to is part of the font (font height - cap height). Try using a font called Space Age to see what I mean.